# Why is with malloc initialized pointer a nullpointer?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm quite sure it's a simple error, still, I can't find it. Can someone spot the error? I handle the arrays `weights` and `momentumVelocity` the same. But after the function ends and I try to use the `momentumVelocity` it is a null pointer. `weights` on the other side is initialized.

The `randomizeNeuron(...)` function does only change the values, in this function monumentumVelocity` exists, too.

```
typedef struct{
    double output;
    int numWeights;
    double* weights;
    double* momentumVelocity;
    double wBias;
    double error;
    double inputSum;
}NeuronTanh;

typedef struct{
    int numNeurons;
    NeuronTanh* neurons;
}Layer;

typedef struct{
    int numLayers;
    Layer* layers;
    double prevError;
    double currentError;
    double currentLearningRate;
}Network;



void initializeNetwork(Network* network){
    //malloc stuff
    network->numLayers = NUMBER_LAYERS;
    network->layers = malloc(NUMBER_LAYERS * sizeof(Layer));
    network->layers[0].numNeurons = SIZE_INPUT_LAYER;
    network->layers[1].numNeurons = SIZE_HIDDEN_LAYER1;
    network->layers[2].numNeurons = SIZE_HIDDEN_LAYER2;
    network->layers[3].numNeurons = SIZE_OUTPUT_LAYER;

    for(int currentLayerIndex=0; currentLayerIndex<network->numLayers;++currentLayerIndex){
        Layer *l = &network->layers[currentLayerIndex];
        l->neurons = malloc(l->numNeurons * sizeof(NeuronTanh));
        for(int j=0; j<l->numNeurons; ++j){
            if(currentLayerIndex==0){
                l->neurons[j].numWeights = SIZE_INPUT;
            }else{
                l->neurons[j].numWeights = network->layers[currentLayerIndex-1].numNeurons;
            }
            l->neurons[j].weights = malloc((l->neurons[j].numWeights) * sizeof(double));
            l->neurons[j].momentumVelocity = malloc((l->neurons[j].numWeights) * sizeof(double));
            randomizeNeuron(&(l->neurons[j]), getmaxInitValue(network, currentLayerIndex));
        }
    }

    network->currentError = 0;
    network->currentLearningRate = LEARNING_RATE;
    network->prevError = 0;
}
```

Comment: what is `Network` and `Layer`? Wht's the definition?

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I would check immediately before and after the call to randomizeNeuron, to see if it is somehow stepping on the memory, since you're passing in the structure holding weights and momentumVelocity pointers.  Would also help to include that function.

Comment: Sorry, I just already feel bad asking such simple questions. Thought it was not necessary

Comment: Based on your claims, it seems like `randomizeNeuron` might be causing the problem.  But since you didn't include it in your post, not much more can be said.

Comment: @DBug I already checked with the GDB. The pointer exists during and after  the `randomizeNeuron` function, but after the `initializeNetwork` function it is a null pointer. How can it get lost?

Comment: The `malloc()` call may simply have failed, in which case it will have returned `NULL`.  You do not check for that, but you should, for *every* `malloc()` call.

Comment: one thing with programming, you can never "assume" that an error is NOT in a specific location.  The littlest typos, like putting in a ';' where you did not mean to can drastically affect the behavior of a program.

Comment: Not only will a mcve help us point you to the bug, but by narrowing down the error you might even find it yourself.

Comment: Why doesn't code check the return value of `malloc()`?

Comment: Yeah I agree with @JohnBollinger . Malloc should be failed in your case

Comment: Note that `malloc()` can return `NULL` and **not** fail as when `malloc(l->numNeurons * sizeof(NeuronTanh));` --> `malloc(0 * sizeof(NeuronTanh));`  So if `l->neurons[j].numWeights == 0` then a `NULL momentumVelocity` is OK.

Comment: So I checked with the gdb the value of the `momentumVelocity' before and after the `randomizeNeuron()`, but there was no error. The pointer gets lost after `initializeNetwork` function ended

Comment: I don't buy that "The pointer gets lost after `initializeNetwork` function ended."  Only automatic variables can ever be "lost".  If the value of any other datum changes then it is because something changed it.  And this is where we return to a call for an MCVE.

Comment: Yes, I spotted the error, and now I turn of my computer in shame. Earlier I used a single variable instead of an array as `momentumVelocity`. So I initialized it with 0. Now after changing it into an array I forgot to delete that line and that caused the reason. I'm very sorry for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

IF there are no other hidden problems, AND you are using the same calculation in both calls to malloc:

(l->neurons[j].numWeights) * sizeof(double)

then the malloc is failing and returning a null pointer. In other words, you don't have sufficient contiguous free memory to perform the allocation. I don't know the value of (l->neurons[j].numWeights) : if it's a huge number and you don't have a lotta RAM then that could be the problem.

Try swapping the two calls to malloc and see if the second one fails. That will tell you a lot.

Comment: thanks, I tried that, but the numNeurons is a value smaller 10, so it made no difference. There is definitely enough free memory

Comment: But what happened when you tried it? Did the second malloc fail or the first one? Did the error follow the line of code or did it stay in place?